# How does the Simplex method actually work?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

I learned about the simplex method, how to pivot by hand before commercial grade solvers were introduced. And I’m still a little foggy on what slack variables and objectives are actually doing.

My current understanding is that pivots are based on Gaussian elimination. This method solves systems of equations and can’t (directly) accept inequalities as inputs.

So the simplex method introduces slack variables and a tableau. At ever pivot, a new system of equations is dynamically generated and it either does (or does not) optimize the objective.

The optimal solution will always occur an intersection of variables.

Once the negative numbers are purged from the bottom row of the tableau, the system no longer generates new systems of equations and has arrived at the optima.

So far, am on I on the right track?

Comment: It is not wrong. For $\geq$-constraint you additionally introduce artificial variables. And the optimal value must not only an intersection of two constraints.  If the objective function is parallel to one of the constraints you may have multiple solutions.

Comment: One follow up, @callculus42, will the optimal solution always be visited last? And if not, how does the tableau maintain awareness of best solution visited thus far?

Comment: If the optimal solution is found then the algorithm stops and of course it is then the last vertex which is be visited. That doesn't mean that all the other vertices has been visited before.

Comment: @callculus42, this is fascinating that the algorithm need not visit every vertex to know that it’s found the optimal solution. I suppose branch and bound doesn’t need to either. Perhaps part of the logic of simplex is eliminating future vertices to “pivot to”.